# composite vs surrogate primary key

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I am designing a database with the following requirements:

- An organization can exist on its own
- An organization can have any number of distinct terms (date range)
- An organization can have any number of survey types (student, teacher, parent, etc)
- A survey form is assigned a term and survey type

A structure for this might be:

**Organization**

```
 - OrganizationId INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
```

**Term**

```
 - TermId INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
 - OrganizationId INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Organization(OrganizationId)
```

**SurveyType**

```
 - SurveyTypeId IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
 - OrganizationId INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Organization(OrganizationId)
```

**SurveyForm**

```
 - SurveyFormId INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
 - SurveyTypeId INT NOT NULL REFERENCES SurveyType(SurveyTypeId)
 - TermId INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Term(TermId)
```

That structure keeps with what seems to be a popular emphasis on a single surrogate primary key. However that structure sacrifices data integrity because it is very easy for a `SurveyForm` record to have a `TermId` or `SurveyTypeId` from different `Organization`s.

To address data integrity, it would seem you would have to add `OrganizationId` and use it in the composite keys `(OrganizationId, SurveyTypeId)` and `(OrganizationId, TermId)`. That is somewhat tolerable in this example but as the schema becomes more complete, the composite key sizes increase.

So my question is, how do people generally approach this now (most references online are from 2008 when I think its possible there were different database design concerns)? As a corollary, when is it acceptable to add foreign keys to a table to reduce the number of tables joined for common expressions?

Comment: You can always keep composite keys for integrity of the diamond-shaped structure, and _add_ surrogate keys to keep connections with other tables manageable...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Academically speaking, you can migrate the Organization key along both lineages. That's just 4 bytes, after all:

```
create table dbo.Organization (
    OrganizationId INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
);
go

create table dbo.Term (
    TermId INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    OrganizationId INT NOT NULL REFERENCES dbo.Organization(OrganizationId),
    primary key (OrganizationId, TermId)
);
go

create table dbo.SurveyType (
    SurveyTypeId int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    OrganizationId INT NOT NULL REFERENCES dbo.Organization(OrganizationId),
    primary key (OrganizationId, SurveyTypeId)
);
go

create table dbo.SurveyForm (
    SurveyFormId INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    OrganizationId int not null,
    SurveyTypeId INT NOT NULL,
    TermId INT NOT NULL,
    primary key (OrganizationId, SurveyTypeId, TermId),
    foreign key (OrganizationId, TermId) references dbo.Term (OrganizationId, TermId),
    foreign key (OrganizationId, SurveyTypeId) references dbo.SurveyType (OrganizationId, SurveyTypeId)
);
go
```

These tables definitely violate some NF, I don't remember which one exactly, but I'm sure you can handle it yourself.

While this design approach can almost be considered a must for a warehouse (esp. if you aggregate data from different sources), I would never recommend it for any real-life OLTP. Much simpler solution would be:

- Perform all modifications via a stored procedure, which will have proper checks against this kind of possible discrepancy.
- Make sure that no user would have permissions to directly add / modify data in the dbo.SurveyForm, thus circumventing the business rules implemented in the aforementioned SP.

Comment: Awesome and insightful answer. On a side note, of the many resources (online, books) I stumble upon on database design, I often do not find this kind of practical problem and solution. Would you have any recommendation?

Comment: @user209974, this design is usually considered excessive (and rightfully so), that's why you don't normally see it anywhere. Not all consistency checks can, or should, be implemented on the schema level. Usually you would want to find some balance between strictness and usability. Regarding the literature, an old incunabula by Connolly and Begg, "Database Systems: A Practical Approach to Design, Implementation, and Management" is still relevant. The subject has barely changed in the last 30 years, so any edition should be good enough. And, nothing beats practice and real-world experience.

Answer (score 0):

I think there could be a way to avoid circular references, firstly by defining who really depends on who and removing redundant dependencies.

The question is... are `Organization`s allowed to be randomly associated to `Term`s without caring about any `Survey` association? I wonder if `Organization`s really need to be associated to a `Term` directly or indirectly through `Survey`s. If, for example, an `Organization` CANNOT be associated to a `Term` that is not associated to the `Organization`'s `Survey` then the Organization-Term relationship is useless, if it is the other way around, then the Organization-SurveyType is not needed

Comment: I tried to give a very simple example but there would be more tables that depend on Term as a concept but not Survey (ie: ActivityForm). In addition you may reuse an Organization's SurveyType in multiple Terms and have Terms with multiple SurveyTypes. Any non-circular structure would result in duplication of one of the other at the very least.